# Populating backend script for Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a web front end to do various management tasks with Django. I've never needed a front end but now they want different BU's to be able to utilize them and they need something pretty to press a button on. So what I want to do is:

1. User inputs form data and submits it
2. Site access's external script using the post data as args
3. User is redirected to confirmation page

Right now I can post data and I can run the script with args, I just don't know how to combine the two. Any help or hints on what I should look into would be greatly appreciated. I didn't post snippets because I'd have to sterilize them but upon request I can if it's needed in order to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to interact directly is to leverage Ajax, whereby you use Ajax Post to send `JSON` to Django and then handle the arguments as a `dict()`. Here is an example:

In browser (JQuery/JavaScript):

```
    function newModule() {

        var my_data = $("#my_element").val(); // Whatever value you want to be sent.

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'modules' %}",       // Handler as defined in Django URLs. 
            type: "POST",                     // Method.
            dataType: "json",                 // Format as JSON (Default).
            data: {
                path: my_data,                // Dictionary key (JSON). 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: 
                         '{{ csrf_token }}'   // Unique key.
            },

            success: function (json) {

                // On success do this.

            },

            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

                // On failure do this. 

            }

        });
```

In server engine (Python):

```
def handle(request):

    # Post request containing the key.  
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'my_data' in request.POST.keys():

        # Retrieving the value.
        my_data = request.POST['my_data']

    # ...
```

Now all you need to do is to direct your HTML form to call the JavaScript function and communicate the data to the engine.

To redirect the user to another page upon success, you can use this in your `success` function:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

Which simulates a reaction similar to that of clicking on an anchor tag (link).

Hope this helps.